# Random number generator min and max-bounded, not working?

Tags: c++, c++11, random

I am using the below code to select a random short between 0 and 4000:

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 mt(rd());
std::uniform_real_distribution<unsigned short> dist(0, 4000);
unsigned short random_no = dist(mt);
```

However, I am getting the value 24,583 returned?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll want to change your code to:

```cpp
std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned short> dist(0, 4000);
```

The `std::uniform_real_distribution` you currently use expects to be used with floating point types only.

---

Now as for the standard because I like to quote!

In Standard(N3797) 26.5.2 `[rand.synopsis]` one of the items is the declaration for the `std::uniform_real_distribution`:

```
// 26.5.8.2.2, class template uniform_real_distribution
template<class RealType = double>
class uniform_real_distribution;
```

which links us to 26.5.8.2.2 for more information, but the important thing is in the declaration already. The templated type is named `RealType` and under

Standard 26.5.1.1 `rand.req.genl]`/1

> Throughout this subclause 26.5, the effect of instantiating a template:
>
> > ...
> >     d) that has a template type parameter named **RealType** is undefined unless the corresponding template
> >     argument is cv-unqualified and is one of float, double, or long double.

Comment: This is slightly different to my original question, but do you know how would I create random float numbers to x decimal places? I know how to create random floats, but not to x decimal places.

Comment: @user997112 [`generate_canonical`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/generate_canonical)